# Set width of <li> depending on the number of children

Tags: html, css

Suppose the number of list children can be dynamically changed. How do I set the width of a list item accordingly such that the total width is 100%?

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    ...
  </ul>
<nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  display: table;
}
ul {
  display: table-row;
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100/numberOfChildren?;
}
```

Comment: how you expecting view? in default list style? or in a row?

Comment: If OP were expecting it to look like a default vertical list they probably wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to mention that the list is used for navigation. The question has been re-edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is with flexbox, although [support is still not quite complete](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) and you may need to add a whole swathe of prefixes for older browsers in case they matter (I'm only including the required prefixes here and omitting the rest for brevity):

```
nav ul {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
    display: block;
    -webkit-flex: auto;
    flex: auto;
}
```

A more cross-browser compatible solution is to use `display: table` with a fixed layout:

```
nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

nav ul {
    display: table-row;
}

nav ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Notice that in neither solution is there a `width` declaration on the list items — this is all calculated automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jsfiddle to achieve this through js .

//DOM Elements

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
    <input id="new_text" type="text" />
<ul id='ulid'>
  <li>A</li>
</ul>
```

// CSS

```
li{
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;   
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    background-color: #F00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;   
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

//JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var text1 = $('#new_text').val();
            var obj=document.createElement('li');
            var newContent = document.createTextNode(text1); 
            obj.appendChild(newContent);
            $('#ulid').append(obj);

            var newWidth = (parseInt($('#ulid').width())/parseInt($('#ulid').children().length))-parseInt($('#ulid').children().length);

            $('li').css({'width':newWidth});
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dipak_chandran/ju83dkv4/